# Exclude Header from Last Page

Tags: crystal-reports

On the `Section Expert`, what do I have to do to exclude a header from showing on the last page?

I believe I have to go to `Section Expert` > Under `Common` > Change something in the formula in `Suppress (No Drill-Down)`

I just don't know the formula to include

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found it. For those looking:

On the `Design` tab, go to the section you want to hide and click `Section Expert`

Then go to `Suppress (No Drill-Down)` and enter the following in the formula editor:

```
(onlastrecord)
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to hide something on the first page, you can use:

```
Not (onfirstrecord)
```